# PHP/MySQL says success when updating an record, but no changes in table

Tags: php, mysql

Really simple question which I can't figure out. Code to update table :

```
$loc = $_POST['sql_id'];
$link = $_POST['link'];
$sql_c = $_POST['name_c'];
$val = $_POST['val'];
$query = "UPDATE $link SET $sql_c='$val' WHERE id='$loc' ";

if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
echo "Success!";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
}
```

It returns Success!, but there are no changes in the table. What am I missing here?

Console log from JS side

```
 (
    [id] => 2
    [link] => Test123
    [name_c] => i1
    [val] => Texx
)
```

Table name is Test123 with columns id,paid,i1,i2,i3,i4,i5

Comment: Is your query correct if you execute it directly in your table ?

Comment: Start with checking `$_POST` values and see if any row in your table fits them.

Comment: I added more information to the first post. I mean I have this '$result_l = $conn->query("UPDATE event SET length='$i_c' WHERE id='$id' ");' query on another file and this is working.

Comment: Use [`affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) method to get number of rows affected from the UPDATE query.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would have helped you here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `$_POST['id'];` not `$_POST['sql_id'];` according to your code.

Comment: Jeez...That's what you get for programming 10 hours straight, small typos. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `$conn->query()` method returns an object if success or `FALSE` if an error occurred. Could you paste the result of your `$conn->query()` call?

So if your query is `$result_l = $conn->query("UPDATE event SET length='$i_c' WHERE id='$id' ");` just do a `var_dump($result_l);` and post it here.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it was just a typo.